# mysql_free_result() seg faults when mysql_store_result() is called in a different function

Tags: c++, mysql

I am programming in C++ and wanted to wrap `mysql_store_result()` in a function that surrounds the call in a mutex. This results in a seg fault when I call `mysql_free_result()`. If I don't have `mysql_store_result()` in a function and just wrap it in a mutex it works fine.

```
void getList() {
    if (query == SUCCESS) {
        MYSQL_RES *res_set;

        //MySQLStoreResult(res_set);

        // If I uncomment the line above the program set faults below.
        // If I uncomment the lines below the program works fine.

        /*mutex.lock();
        res_set = mysql_store_result(mysql);
        mutex.unlock();*/

        unsigned int num_rows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);

        if (num_rows > 0) {
            //loop through all the rows using mysql_fetch_rows()

            mysql_free_result(res_set);  // seg fault
        }
    }
}

void MySQLStoreResult(MYSQL_RES *res_set) {
    mutex.lock();
    res_set = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: You kind of forgot to ask a question. Have you tried to debug? Did you find the line of code that segfaults? Did you try running under valgrind? What help do you want?

Comment: It seg faults on 'mysql_free_result(res_set)' I am wondering why it only seg faults when 'mysql_store_result()' and 'mysql_free_result()' are not called in the same function.

Comment: You've over-simplified your code and it doesn't make sense as you've posted it.  `res_set` goes out of scope so code outside that block shouldn't compile unless you have 2 different `res_set` variables at different scopes.  And clearly it's not a single code block since you've declared a function there...

Comment: `MYSQL_RES *res_set;` And then -- nothing. I see nowhere where `res_set` points to a valid `MYSQL_RES`, but you pass this uninitialized pointer around.  Where does the pointer get initialized?

Comment: @tehAlgorithmist That's the line of your code that calls the code that eventually segfaults. What is the line of code that actually segfaults though?

Comment: Sorry about my first code snippet. I updated it to better reflect my code. My apologies.

Here is some output from gdb about the actual line that segfaults.
#00x00007ffff6301bc0 in free_root () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
#1  0x00007ffff62e6644 in free_rows () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
#2  0x00007ffff62e6e1d in mysql_free_result () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18

Comment: @tehAlgorithmist You still didn't answer why you are passing an uninitialized `MYSQL_RES` pointer to the `mysql_num_rows` function. There really is no answer, as all signs are is that it is wrong.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize that I wasn't initializing it at first. You're question prompted me to realize that I needed to pass a double pointer. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @tehAlgorithmist - See my answer on the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem right away:

```
void MySQLStoreResult(MYSQL_RES *res_set) {
    mutex.lock();
    res_set = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

That `res_set` pointer is local to that function.  You do not see the changes when you return to the caller.  So in the calling code, you are using an uninitialized pointer.

That function should be this:

```
void MySQLStoreResult(MYSQL_RES *& res_set) {
    mutex.lock();
    res_set = mysql_store_result(mysql);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

You must pass a reference to the pointer.

Also, you should use RAII synchronization objects.  What if you change mysql_store_result() to a function that can `throw`, or you add more code that can `throw`?  Your mutex will remain locked due to the `unlock` call never being executed.